# Linking variables into executable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I like to understand how we can link a global variable into an executable using Makefile.
I compile few C source files and create an executable from it. I compute the md5sum of this executable and want to attach it to another executable and make it available as a global variable in the other executable. By doing this, I can check in the second executable whether the first one has been modified and if it is then I could change some operation.

Although I can do it in the second executable at the beginning of its execution but I would like to stick with this approach as I could learn how to create global variables and link to binary directly in Makefile.

Comment: I would suggest you figure out how to do it without a makefile first, and then automate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  (I also recommend writing a complete question before pressing submit.  Fortunately, very few people saw the incomplete first version.)  You realize, of course, that attaching the MD5 checksum to the file will change the MD5 checksum of the file, thus rendering the value irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for comment, yea I had trouble posting and clicked post too soon. Well, what I intend is, add the MD5 checksum of some other file in my project and that value I need it as a global variable.(I’m not computing MD5 of the same binary and appending to it). Ultimately I will use that md5 value to check if that other file has been changed or not (using this executable) and if it has changed I will operate it differently.

Comment: You can, and in this case should, update the question to clarify what you are trying to do.  For example, 'I want to attach this md5sum as a global variable in another executable so that the second executable can check whether the first has been modified and modify its behaviour accordingly'.  Or something along those general lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
md5sum.c: program_1
    echo 'const char md5sum_program_1[] = "'$$(md5sum program_1)'";' > md5sum.c

OBJECTS2 = ... md5sum.o

program_2: ${OBJECTS2}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS2} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

The first line says that the source file `md5sum.c` depends on the first program, `program_1`; when `md5sum.c` does not exist or is older than `program_1`, the command is executed.  The command creates the definition of a global variable `md5sum_program_1` and initializes it with the output from `md5sum`.

The `OBJECTS2` macro includes all the object files needed for `program_2` plus `md5sum.o`.  The last command links the program.